# How can I convert this iptables mark-user rule to firewald rich language?

Tags: iptables, firewalld

I'm trying to convert [the scripts here](https://github.com/bendikro/deluge-vpn.git) from raw iptables to firewalld rich rules. For example, these rules:

```
# Mark packets from $VPNUSER
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT ! --dest $LAN_NETWORK  -m owner --uid-owner $VPNUSER -j MARK --set-mark $MARK_ID -m comment --comment "${COMMENT}"
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT --dest $LAN_NETWORK -p udp --dport $DNS_PORT -m owner --uid-owner $VPNUSER -j MARK --set-mark $MARK_ID -m comment --comment "${COMMENT}"
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT --dest $LAN_NETWORK -p tcp --dport $DNS_PORT -m owner --uid-owner $VPNUSER -j MARK --set-mark $MARK_ID -m comment --comment "${COMMENT}"
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT ! --src $LAN_NETWORK -j MARK --set-mark $MARK_ID -m comment --comment "${COMMENT}"

# Allow responses
iptables -A INPUT -i $VPNIF -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "${COMMENT}"

# Allow bittorrent
iptables -A INPUT -i $VPNIF -p tcp --match multiport --dport $BITTORRENT_LISTEN_PORTS -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "${COMMENT}"
iptables -A INPUT -i $VPNIF -p udp --match multiport --dport $BITTORRENT_LISTEN_PORTS -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "${COMMENT}"

# Block everything incoming on $VPNIF
iptables -A INPUT -i $VPNIF -j REJECT -m comment --comment "${COMMENT}"

# Set DNS for $VPNUSER
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT --dest $LAN_NETWORK -p udp --dport $DNS_PORT -m owner --uid-owner $VPNUSER -j DNAT --to-destination $DNS_IP1 -m comment --comment "${COMMENT}"
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT --dest $LAN_NETWORK -p tcp --dport $DNS_PORT -m owner --uid-owner $VPNUSER -j DNAT --to-destination $DNS_IP1 -m comment --comment "${COMMENT}"
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT --dest $LAN_NETWORK -p udp --dport $DNS_PORT -m owner --uid-owner $VPNUSER -j DNAT --to-destination $DNS_IP2 -m comment --comment "${COMMENT}"
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT --dest $LAN_NETWORK -p tcp --dport $DNS_PORT -m owner --uid-owner $VPNUSER -j DNAT --to-destination $DNS_IP2 -m comment --comment "${COMMENT}"

# Let $VPNUSER access lo and $VPNIF
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -m owner --uid-owner $VPNUSER -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "${COMMENT}"
iptables -A OUTPUT -o $VPNIF -m owner --uid-owner $VPNUSER -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "${COMMENT}"

# All packets on $VPNIF needs to be masqueraded
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $VPNIF -j MASQUERADE -m comment --comment "${COMMENT}"

# Reject connections from predator ip going over $NETIF
iptables -A OUTPUT ! --src $LAN_NETWORK -o $NETIF -j REJECT -m comment --comment "${COMMENT}"
```

The man page firewalld.richlanguage has no mention of --uid-owner or --ctstate . There is one sentence of documentation for the "mark" Action:

```
With mark all packets will be marked in the PREROUTING chain in the mangle table with the mark and mask combination.
```

The documentation for the "Direct" interface says that the entire interface has been superseded by policies. The documentation for firewalld policies refers to firewalld.richlanguage. That's why I'm asking here.

Comment: Have you possibly found a solution?
I am trying to convert `-m owner --uid-owner` rules to a policy...